# Query timestamp and value at same time in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort my entries by their `star` count as "Top of Week", "Top of Month", "Top of All Time". Multiple `orderBy` is not allowed so I can't query `star` and `timestamp` childs at same time. How sould I structure, index and query my data?

I am using REST API in my sotfware. But answers using SDK also can help me. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a numeric star count as a property.

Use indexed properties that have the year and month+year combined with the star count in a way that sorts the way you want like:

```
"stars": 123,
"stars-by-year": "2017-000000000123",
"stars-by-month": "2017-04-000000000123"
```

Then you can use startAt() to query for each. It's not clear if the date is for stars given this month or items created this month but this should work for both.